# How do I add new itens in all elmentor forms?

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I'm currently working on my website and I'm trying to add new items to all Elementor forms. To achieve this, I've used the action hook 'elementor_pro/forms/new_record' in the following code snippet placed in my functions.php file:

```
function add_custom_field_to_forms($record, $ajax_handler) {
    $form_name = $record->get_form_settings('form_name');
    $form = $record->get_form_settings();

    if ('Experiencia-Realizada' === $form_name || 'Formulário B2B - LP Principal (Menu B2B)' === $form_name || 'Fale-Conosco' === $form_name) {
        return $form;
    }

    $CityAndState = array(
        'name' => 'Cidade/Estado',
        'label' => 'Cidade/Estado',
        'type' => 'text',
        'required' => true,
    );

    $FoodAndDrinks = array(
        'name' => 'Incluir alimentos e bebidas?',
        'label' => 'Incluir alimentos e bebidas?',
        'type' => 'text',
        'required' => false,
    );

    $Prices = array(
        'name' => 'PREVISÃO DE ORÇAMENTO DISPONÍVEL PARA A AÇÃO',
        'label' => 'PREVISÃO DE ORÇAMENTO DISPONÍVEL PARA A AÇÃO',
        'type' => 'select',
        'required' => false,
        'options' => array(
            '8000-15000' => 'De R$8.000 a R$15.000',
            '15000-50000' => 'De R$15.000 a R$50.000',
            '50000-100000' => 'De R$50.000 a R$100.000',
            '100000+' => 'À partir de R$100.000',
        ),
    );
 // Insert the fields at the antepenultimate position
    array_splice($form['fields'], -2, 0, array($CityAndState, $FoodAndDrinks, $Prices));

    $record->set_form_settings($form);
}
add_action('elementor_pro/forms/new_record', 'add_custom_field_to_forms', 10, 2);
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be working as expected. I'm wondering if there's something I'm missing or if there's an alternative approach that I should consider.

Could someone please guide me on how to successfully add new items to all Elementor forms using the 'elementor_pro/forms/new_record' action hook? Any assistance or insights would be greatly appreciated.